# how to use dataset api like dataset.output(outputFormat) in latest flink1.14 or flink1.15 table/sql api

Tags: dataset, apache-flink, flink-sql, outputformat

I got a project use dataset api like dataset.output(outputFormat). The OutputFormat is userDefined(write batch data to neo4j) so I  want to keep it, but I could not find any table/sql api in latest version in flink use outputFormat. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Flink 1.14, the implementation of the Table/SQL API no longer relies at all on the DataSet API. Those relational APIs now rely exclusively on the DataStream API for both batch and streaming use cases.

I suggest you ask on the Flink user mailing list for guidance. It may be possible to implement a custom OutputFormat to use with the Table API. Another possibility might be to convert the Table to a DataStream, and then use `writeUsingOutputFormat` (but that has been deprecated).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try  user mailing list if necessary